# C code using libxml2 giving compile time errors on cygwin on Win 7

Tags: c, xml, gcc, cygwin, libxml2

I am trying to write a xml parser in C using the libxml2 on cygwin on my Win 7 machine.
When i am trying to compile the code it is giving me compile time errors. Can someone help me out on this.

```
ad@ad-PC /cygdrive/c/Users/ad/Desktop
$ gcc xmlparser.c -I /cygdrive/c/Users/ad/Desktop/libxml2-2.7.8.win32/include/ -L /cygdrive/c/Users/ad/Desktop/libxml2-2.7.8.win32/lib/libxml2.lib -o pxml
In file included from /cygdrive/c/Users/ad/Desktop/libxml2-2.7.8.win32/include/libxml/parser.h:807,
             from xmlparser.c:8:
/cygdrive/c/Users/ad/Desktop/libxml2-2.7.8.win32/include/libxml/encoding.h:28:19: iconv.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /cygdrive/c/Users/ad/Desktop/libxml2-2.7.8.win32/include/libxml/parser.h:807,
             from xmlparser.c:8:
/cygdrive/c/Users/ad/Desktop/libxml2-2.7.8.win32/include/libxml/encoding.h:146: error: parse error before "iconv_t"
/cygdrive/c/Users/ad/Desktop/libxml2-2.7.8.win32/include/libxml/encoding.h:146: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
/cygdrive/c/Users/ad/Desktop/libxml2-2.7.8.win32/include/libxml/encoding.h:147: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
xmlparser.c: In function `main':
xmlparser.c:21: error: `filename' undeclared (first use in this function)
xmlparser.c:21: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once  
xmlparser.c:21: error: for each function it appears in.)
xmlparser.c:29: error: parse error before ')' token
xmlparser.c: At top level:
xmlparser.c:34: error: parse error before string constant
xmlparser.c:34: error: conflicting types for 'printf'
xmlparser.c:34: note: a parameter list with an ellipsis can't match an empty parameter name list declaration
xmlparser.c:34: error: conflicting types for 'printf'
xmlparser.c:34: note: a parameter list with an ellipsis can't match an empty parameter name list declaration
xmlparser.c:34: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
```

The code ::

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <libxml/parser.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    xmlDoc *document;
    xmlNode *root , *node , *first_child;

    if(argc < 2) 
    {
        printf("\n Error No filename specified \n");
        return 1;
    }

    filename = argv[1];

    document = xmlReadFile(filename,NULL,0);
    root = xmlDocGetRootElement(document);

    printf("\n Root is ::%s:: <%i> \n",root->name,root->type);
    first_child = root->children;

    for(node = first_child;node,node = node->next)
    {
        printf("\n Child is ::%s:: <%i> \n",node -> name, node->type);
    }

    printf("\n END \n");
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: We really need the code to try and help... but from the errors... declare `filename`

Comment: Did you try to build it on say, Linux?

Comment: I seriously doubt that the library declares a function named `main`, so the problem is in your code, which you aren't showing, and not in the library. Show us the code.

Comment: Can't see any code, just the error messages.

Comment: @amn No i tried it only on windows on cygwin

Comment: You have the error messages and you don't appear to make any sense of them. That's why. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it unambiguously that `filename` is not declared and yet you're trying to use it here:

```
filename = argv[1];
```

There's also a wrong punctuator here:

```
for(node = first_child;node,node = node->next)
```

It has to be `;` instead of `,`.

Comment: ..yes the two you pointed out are silly mistakes i made i corrected them. But my concern regarding the errors i getting from the libxml2 header files i getting at the top. Can you please have a look at that and what can be the reason for that

Comment: Clearly, from those same errors it follows that the compiler is unable to find the header file `iconv.h`. You either don't have it, or you haven't specified the path for finding it.

Comment: I have given the include folder path in the gcc & checked for the header file iconv.h but it is not there. Do i have download someother library also to use libxml2 on windows apart from the regular one?

Comment: [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv). Your library depends on this library and you haven't installed it.

Comment: [Nice text/pic describing library dependencies](http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html).